# Loopback findOrCreate creates new records even if there is an existing record

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

As per my understanding of the loopback documentation Persistedmodel.findOrCreate should find a model according to the query and return it, or create a new entry in the database if the model does not exist.

What I have noticed in my case is that it creates a new entry irrespective of whether there is an existing entry.

Not sure what I am missing. Here is my code:

teams-joined.json

```
{
  "name": "teamsJoined",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "teamID": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "playerID":{
      "type":"string",
      "required":true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

teams-joined.js

```
let queryThatWorks = {where:{
              and: [
                  {teamID: teamID}
              ]
            }
         };

let query = {where:{
              and: [
                  {teamID: teamID},
                  {playerID: req.currentUser.id},
              ],
            }
         };
let joinTeamsData = {
              teamID: teamID,
              playerID: req.currentUser.id,
            };
console.log(query.where,'query');
teamsJoined.findOrCreate(query, joinTeamsData,
     function(err, data, created) {
                console.log(data,created);
              });
```

When I cal the API multiple times, this is what I get

```
{ and:
   [ { teamID: 'bf36e0-93a5-11e8-a8f4-9d86f4dd79ee' },
     { playerID: '5b20887bb6563419505c4590' } ] } 'query'
{ teamID: 'bf36e0-93a5-11e8-a8f4-9d86f4dd79ee',
  playerID: '5b20887bb6563419505c4590',
  id: 5b61798534fa410d2b1d900a } 'data'
true 'created'
{ and:
   [ { teamID: 'bf36e0-93a5-11e8-a8f4-9d86f4dd79ee' },
     { playerID: '5b20887bb6563419505c4590' } ] } 'query'
{ teamID: 'bf36e0-93a5-11e8-a8f4-9d86f4dd79ee',
  playerID: '5b20887bb6563419505c4590',
  id: 5b61798634fa410d2b1d900b } 'data'
true 'created'
```

I expected it to return false for created and just return the existing data.
This works fine when I use the 'queryThatWorks' query from my code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `and` operator in your where clause. See [findOrCreate](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findorcreate).

```
{ where: { teamID: teamID, playerID: req.currentUser.id } }
```

You can include your data into your filter like that:

```
{ where: joinTeamsData }
```

To return specific fields in your return statement, you can use the fields option in your query.

Finally, try this:

```
let data = {
    teamID: teamID,
    playerID: req.currentUser.id,
};

let filter = { where: data };

teamsJoined.findOrCreate(filter, data,
    function(err, instance, created) {
        console.log(instance, created);
    }
);
```

Comment: I removed the `and` operator and tried. Still the same. As per the where filter documentation it seems to suggest that to check with 2 keys, you need to use `and` operator. But I guess irrespective of the operator the result is still the same. 

The filter option won't work for me since my data model has the default id. Which is unique for each data entry.

Comment: Can we see the player and team models?

Comment: I haven't created team and player models. There are no relationships defined as well to connect teamsJoined to any other models. Would that be the reason for the weird behaviour?